# How to change the user's APEX form nulls into a static value?

Tags: oracle-apex

I'm using oracle apex and the business needs requires me to set the value to a static result if the user didn't type in anything. What's the best way to achieve this?

should I use a trigger, a dynamic action with nvl expression, or something else?

I've attempted using a dynamic action, but it changes it at before submission, which is not what I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best (clean, easy to read and understand, easy to maintain)  way is to create an after submit computation on each item with a server side condition of "ITEM IS NULL". Don't use triggers or dynamic actions for this.